# How to read space from one text file and put into another file line by line

Tags: batch-file, dos

In text file having the some space, I need to these space with line in next text file.
for e.g in a.txt:

```
                   c:/abc/text
                   c:/bec/text
```

I need the same into another file, But when I am doing in batch script, space have removed and shows like:

```
c:/abc/text
c:/bec/text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (C:\text.txt) do echo %%a>>C:\new.txt
```

Comment: using your logic its removed the spaces but i need spaced into another text file.

Comment: No, it leaves the spaces in, I just copied your text and put in in a text file and it works fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have already put one delims=; for another case can I put another delims?

Comment: Possibly, try and it and see?